# How to determine proportion of a mixture of 2 different normal distributions

Tags: normal-distribution

Adult Northern and Southern Yeti heights can each be represented as normal distributions:
Yeti Type   mean        sd
Northern    92in        4.5in
Southern    95in        4.2in

20,000 Yeti adults attend a concert, each one’s height being recorded upon entry.

What could one say about the proportion of Northern vs Southern Yeti at the concert based only on the 20K height measurements?

Comment: Seems like you're looking to do [Mixture modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model#Gaussian_mixture_model).

Comment: if this is HW please add the self-study tag

Comment: Thank you, neerajt.  Yes, it seems that 1D Expectation Maximization. I am surprised at the complexity but happy to have come across this explanation: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72774/numerical-example-to-understand-expectation-maximization.  And, no Antoine, this isn't homework -- just my colorful way of describing a real world problem I am trying to solve.  Thanks.