# EM-algorithm and missing data

Tags: mixed-model

Does EM-algorithm only work with missing data? If not, what is the idea to assume that we have missing data?

Comment: Any density that can write as$$f_\theta(x)=\int_\mathscr{Y} g_\theta(x,y)\text{d}y$$qualifies for EM, not truly a restriction. Provided you can implement the E step.

Comment: Check also: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72774/numerical-example-to-understand-expectation-maximization/72810#72810

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [Wikipedia for EM algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) has everything you want and it probably explains better than I do. You can also use the EM algorithm for latent variables; no missing data but variables that you can't observe and measure. The idea of the algorithm is to iteratively adjust your missing data/latent variables until your maximum likelihood estimate converges.