# Example of manual implementation of baum-welch algorithm in R

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model, expectation-maximization, baum-welch, forward-backward

Is there any code out there that implements the baum-welch algorithm for a very basic problem? It would be very helpful to actually see the algorithm in action to better understand how it works.

I understand the forward and the backward procedures and already implemented them in R for a simple example. However, up to now, I haven't succeeded in implementing the baum-welch algorithm to actually estimate the parameters of a HMM. [Numerical example to understand Expectation-Maximization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72774/numerical-example-to-understand-expectation-maximization) helped me to grasp the logic of EM. However, I still do not fully understand how this translates to the baum-welch algorithm in a HMM.

Can anyone share native R code (without complex rcpp functions etc.) of a very basic version of the baum-welch algorithm in a simple HMM?

I think that there are many others who would profit from a working example of the algorithm. Something that makes the formulas come alive in a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a DIY answer, with the building blocks provided:

You are probably aware R has an [HMM package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HMM/HMM.pdf). One thing to highlight is that you can view all available  functions in a package as shown [on this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30392542/is-there-a-command-in-r-to-view-all-the-functions-present-in-a-package). And, the final piece of the puzzle: you can view function source code in R [as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function).